# Logical not for media queries selector

Tags: selector, media

Can I do negation of media query selector?
Something like:

```
@media ($mat-xsmall):not() {
  nav {
    // taken from md-card-image styles
    margin-top: -24px !important;
    width: calc(100% + 48px);
    margin: 0 -24px 16px;
  }
}
```